# At the end of the table, I would like the number of times that "yes" appears

Tags: pgfmath

My question is about using counters.

I would like the number of "yes" to appear at the bottom of the table. I don't know how to use counters.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]
\scriptsize
\newcounter{ga}\setcounter{ga}{0}\addtocounter{ga}{0}
\foreach \u in {1,...,20}
\foreach\x in{1,...,20}{
\pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{6}
\pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{1}{6}
\ifthenelse{
\a<4 \AND \b<4\AND \NOT \a =\b}
{\node[blue, draw,circle] at (\x,\u) {sì};\stepcounter{ga};}{\node at (\x,\u) {no}};
\normalsize
%\pgfmathparse{ga}
\pgfmathresult{ga}
%\node at (5,-1) {\the\value{ga}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: You can't use just the name of a LaTeX counter with PGFmath. (That's why `\pgfmathparse{ga}` fails.) `\pgfmathresult` ist just the result, it doesn't accept an argument. But you can't just simply output text (which that is) in a Tikzpicture without a node. (This is why `\pgfmathresult{ga}` doesn't do anything *on* the page.) You've missed a `;` after the no node.

Comment: Grazie per questo primo passo. Se però si scrive "\node at (5,-1) {\pgfmathresult};'", si ottiene  -1.0 che non è ovviamente il numero dei "sì" che sono in tabella

Answer (score 4):

This works. The `\foreach` cycles are properly braced and stepping the counter is done inside `\pgfextra`. The font size is stated at the appropriate place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,tikz}

\newcounter{ga}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]
  \setcounter{ga}{0}
  \foreach \u in {1,...,20}{
    \foreach \x in {1,...,20}{
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{6}
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{1}{6}
      \ifthenelse{\a<4 \AND \b<4 \AND \NOT \a =\b}
        {\node[blue,draw,circle,font=\scriptsize] at (\x,\u) {sì}; \stepcounter{ga}}
        {\node[font=\scriptsize] at (\x,\u) {no};}
    }
  }
  \node at (5,-1) {\thega};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me by 1 minute :-)